# Mongoose - asynchronous call not resolving promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this route in a social media that I'm building that loops through all the users your are following and gets their posts. I am using await and .exec() but the output I am getting is a pending promise.

Route:

```
router.get("/following", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ firebaseUID: req.authId });

    const posts = await user.following.map(async (usr) => {
      await Post.find({ userID: usr.user }).exec();
    });
    console.log(posts);

    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```

The output I am getting from this is `[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]`.

I am unsure why the promise is not being resolved when I am using await in an asynchronous function and .exec()?

Comment: You're missing a `Promise.all` call on your array of promises. You cannot `await` the array that `map` returns.

Comment: Btw, you really shouldn't make one `find` call per user id - fetch them all at once!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling an async method inside `map`, and `map` doesn't wait for the promise to get resolved, but you can use a `for` loop instead.

```
  let posts = []
  for(let i=0; i<user.following.length; i++) {
    posts.push(
      await Post.find({userID: user.following[i].usr }).exec()
    );
  });
 console.log(posts);
```